# MySQL on delete cascade, FK in source table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, customer and address. Customer has column address with FK referencing to table address.

Table customer

```
create table customer
(
    id int(11) not null primary key,
    ...
    address    int(11) null,
    constraint fk_customer_address
        foreign key (address) references address (id)
        on update cascade on delete cascade,
)
```

Table address

```
create table address
(
id int(11) not null primary key,
...
)
```

I want to have address id in customer table, because in future there will be more tables referencing to address table (Users.address, Business.address, etc) and one table for all addresses because of the same format.

When I delete row in customer table, address row stays in DB.

Is it possible to use this FK relation to delete row in address table, or do I have to delete it manually (programmatically)?

Does this mean that when I delete row from address, customer row is deleted as well?

Edit:
Yes, it does.

Comment: ' Is it possible to use this FK relation to delete row in address table' - no it isn't , 'Does this mean when I delete row from address, customer row is deleted as well' - yes it does.

Comment: Would it help if I remove address id from customer and add some generic 'ref_id' to address table?

Comment: It makes more sense to have customer id in address and a column to indicate address type with cid FKd to customer with on delete cascade so that when customer is deleted all addresses are too.However you would need to code to make sure customer always has at least one address.

Comment: Note that depending on the mysql version, foreign keys may not be implemented on MyIsam storage engine. Be sure to use an storage engine that supports Foreign keys.

Comment: *When I delete row in customer table, address row stays in DB. Is it possible to use this FK relation to delete row in address table, or do I have to delete it manually (programmatically)?* Logically incorrect. Imagine that there exists another row which refers to the same address - `customer.address` is not defined as unique. You may delete "lost" addresses from service event procedure.

Comment: @P.Salmon Do I need new column for each table referencing to address table in that case?

Comment: @Akina There should be one-to-one relation between those tables, address should be unique. Thanks for noticing that

Comment: *address should be unique.* This **must** be set in the table structure by according index - add it.

Comment: From the other side - what's the reason for to move the address into separate table?

Comment: @Akina As I mentioned, I would like to store addresses for multiple types (customers, businesses, users, etc.) in same table

Comment: This is a point of potential problem. None prevents two different rows from two different tables refer onto the same address. Do not tell that this is not possible - the structure cannot prevent this. For example as an error during manual correction. In such case this address row deletion due to customer deletion will either fail or make your data inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want customer rows deleted when an address row is deleted. I think the fk would be correct if it was defined as "on delete restrict" or "on delete set null".

So that if you wanted to delete the address record:

- `on delete set null` ➞ All references to that address would be set as null
- `on delete restrict` ➞ You should manually update the address_id it on ALL child tables to some other value (or null) and then delete the parent row

You could somehow avoid the programatic deletion by defining the fk the opposite (that is: address table has a foreign key to customer table, and others)

However, for me this feels somewhat unnatural since you would have to add a new column on the address table for each other table you want to reference. It feels more natural for each table to have the fk of the address.

Another drawback is that it would not allow you to reuse same address on the same table. For example, if two customers would share the same address, you would need to create a row for each of those customers.

With the first solution you would just need a single row on the address table, that could be referenced multiple times on the customer table by different customers.

Of course, your requirements may be a 1:1 relationship. But remember that requirements can change :). And if they do, and you later require to share same address between different rows, you are ready to go with the first solution.

I would use your original approach with a "on delete set null" constraint.